# Jasper Report Unit test case in scala with mockito giving error for static method

Tags: scala, junit, mockito, jasper-reports

I am having "mockito-core" library having version "4.11.0" which supports mocking static methods.
But when I am trying to unit test case below:-

```
import org.Mockito._
import org.Junit.Test

@Test
  def testReportWithValidData() {
....//Mocking
....
val jasperFillManager: MockedStatic[JasperFillManager] = mockStatic(classOf[JasperFillManager])

   jasperFillManager.when(JasperFillManager.fillReport(any(classOf[JasperReport]), any(classOf[java.util.Map[String,Object]]), any(classOf[JRDataSource])))
     .thenReturn(mock(classOf[JasperPrint]))
    enter code here

val result = ...
assertNotNull(result)
}
```

Getting this error:-

```
type mismatch;
 found   : net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint
 required: org.mockito.MockedStatic.Verification
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: I haven't worked with jasper report for a while. Same with mockito. The error says `required: Verification` but `found: JasperPrint`. Maybe the line `.thenReturn(mock(classOf[JasperPrint]))` is the problem. Maybe `.thenReturn(mock(classOf[Verification]))` would fix the error. If that is not the case, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)